# How do I install homebrew on macOS? Error: > -bash: $: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, homebrew, macos-catalina

When I copy/paste this link:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

on the terminal it keeps giving me this error:

> -bash: $: command not found

I don't have much experience at dealing with this type of code. If someone could help me it would be really appreciated. I was trying to install HomeBrew to get some Unitiy packages from their github.

Comment: > /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the leading `$`, which is the prompt, not part of the command. It is to indicate "this is something you should paste on the commandline." The actual command is:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

If you click the "clipboard" icon at [brew.sh](https://brew.sh), it'll copy the correct command to your clipboard.

[image: Pointer to clipboard icon at brew.sh]

Note that this "leading $ prompt" indicator is used throughout the brew.sh site (and is very common in unix-style documentation). So when you see `$ brew install wget`, that means to type "brew install wget" at the command prompt. It does not mean to type `$`.